# data = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 1888

Tags: java

I use Clipboard class to get the text that located in clipboard. But  data = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) throws exception   StringIndexOutOfBoundsException  (id=107)
I don't know why it happened.

```
public static void Do(JTextField textfield ) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IllegalArgumentException {
    String data="";
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();

    if (textfield.getText().isEmpty() || textfield.getText().equals("Enter url here")) {    
         data = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } else {
         URL url = new URL(textfield.getText()+"?report=xml&format=text");
         URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
         InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         String line = "";
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         data=data+line;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of your clipboard are UTF-8 encoded text?

Comment: its XML text. Interesting that this part of code worked fine on the other computer.